# How to set the parameters in the function (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I would like to call the "getRatio" function that has parameters in the onCreate function. When I tried to call the function in onCreate, it is obvious that I required insert some kind of parameters. However, I do not want to fix the value of the parameters such as "getRatio(1,2,3)". What should I do?

Below are the sample:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityReportBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    entries = ArrayList()

    initPieChart()

    getRatio()

}

 private fun getRatio(FoodTotal: Double)
```

Comment: If you just need to pass a single double as a parameter or nothing setting a default parameter (as suggested by Suraj) is fine. Do you also need to pass multiple parameters to the function? (eg `getRatio(1,2,3)`)

Comment: I would like pass multiple parameters, but I do not want to set the value for each parameters.

Comment: You do not want to "fix" the values of the parameters, okay, so what ***do*** you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your parameter using the `vararg` keyword:

```
private fun getRatio(vararg foodTotal: Double) {
    foodTotal.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

This will allow you to pass a variable number of parameters to the function:

```
getRatio()
getRatio(1.0)
getRatio(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```